# Error message when I Request licenses to share my Power Apps app

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have created a Power Apps app and I want to share the link with my colleagues. The page shows that I am using "premium components" and I need to request licenses, therefore I click the "Request licenses" button. As soon as I do, I get this error message

[image]

The app is using SherePoint Lists as "back-end" and also a Power Automate flow.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which premium connector or feature are you using exactly in your app?

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap - Hi Ganesh, I have 3 SharePoint connections to 3 Lists, 1 Microsoft Dataverse Teams and 1 execution of Power Automate flow.